# Prevent flexbox div from going under header sibling when window is resized

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am having trouble preventing a flexbox div from going under its sibling (header). I have the following HTML/CSS structure:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="application">
    <header class="application-header">HEADER</header>
    <div class="application-content">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-header">TITLE</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.application {
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;    
}

.application-header {
    height: 44px;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.application-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 44px);
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 800px;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 555px;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    display: flex;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.content-header {
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    display: flex;
}
```

**IMAGES:**

This is before resizing:

[image: PRE-RESIZE]

This is after resizing. Note that the content is behind the header:

[image: POST-RESIZE]

**What I'm looking for is for after the resizing, the content stays at the top like on the first image and the overflow is *scrollable*.** And also, I want it to be a margin between the content and the header as well. Does anybody know how I can make that div stay at its place and not hide behind the header?

If you need any other information or image, let me know. I'm not very versed in html/css so it might be simpler than it seems.

PS.: I do need the `min-height` on `.content`, or at least a way to limit how much it can shrink.

**EDIT #1:**

```css
.application {
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.application-header {
  height: 44px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.application-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 44px);
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-width: 800px;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 555px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-header {
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html class="">

<head>

</head>

<body class="" style="padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
  <div class="application">
    <header class="application-header" style="background-color: blue;">HEADER</header>
    <div class="application-content" style="background-color: red;">
      <div class="content" style="background-color: greenyellow; color: black;">
        <div class="content-header">TITLE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code posted doesn't reproduce the problem described or illustrated in the images. Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin I have edited the question to show a tested html that reproduces the problem (except for the mispositioned title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to keep the structure full flexbox and keep a `min-height` with a scroll overflow on `.content`. I have changed all the `vh` to `%`, and added a 100% height to body and html, like @カメロン suggested. I also changed which div has `overflow` and `min-height`. But most importantly I added a wrapper on the `.application-content`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.application {
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.application-header {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 44px;
}

.application-wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100% - 44px);
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.application-content {
  flex: 1 1;
  height: calc(100% - 44px);
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-width: 800px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.content-header {
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.content-body {
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 455px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="application">
  <header class="application-header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="application-wrapper">
    <div class="application-content">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-header">TITLE</div>
        <div class="content-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**RESULT:**

Before the resize

[image: BEFORE-RESIZE]

And after the resize:

[image: AFTER-RESIZE]